# Ng2-Dragula not working with Custom filters - issue

Tags: angular, pipe, angular5, ngdraggable

I have two tables , one is source table and another is target table. when i drag the rows from source table to target table i am able to drag the rows but in target table the dragged rows refer to source table instance and due to this when i filter rows in source table and then drag to target table that time wrong data is get dropped in target table. I am new to angular please guide me if i am doing in wrong way. I have updated this code:-

**Source Table :- FinedTunedData
Target Table :- PlanningBoardData**

```
  <tbody [dragula]='"bag"' [dragulaModel]='FineTunedDatas'>     
        <!-- <tr *ngFor="let FineTunedData of FineTunedDatas" dragHandle=".ui-panel-titlebar" (click)="GetCustomerDetailsByArticleID(FineTunedData)"> -->

        <tr *ngFor="let FineTunedData of FineTunedDatas | orderBy: key : reverse | familieFilter: family | searchfilter:filter | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: f, id: 'f' };
          let i = index" (click)="setClickedRow(i)"  [class.active]="i == selectedRow" (click)="GetCustomerDetailsByArticleID(FineTunedData)" 
          >            
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.article_ID}}</td>
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.description}}</td>          
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.stockRAW}}</td>          
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.ordersRAW}}</td>
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.family}}</td>              
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.toProduceForecast}}</td>  
            <td class="th">{{FineTunedData.toProduce}}</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="placeholder" *ngIf="!table1?.length > 0" id="no-drop">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>  
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>



  <tbody  [dragula]='"bag"' [dragulaModel]='PlanningBoardDatas'> 
      <tr *ngFor="let PlanningBoardData of PlanningBoardDatas let i = index"
        [class.active]="i == selectedRow" [attr.data-id]="i" (click)="getLKoqValue(i, FineTunedData)">             
          <td class="th">{{PlanningBoardData.article_ID}}</td>
          <td class="th">{{PlanningBoardData.description}}</td>
          <td class="th">{{PlanningBoardData.navisionCode}}</td>       
          <td class="th">{{PlanningBoardData.stockRAW}}</td> 
          <td class="th">{{PlanningBoardData.ordersRAW}}</td>
          <td class="th">{{PlanningBoardData.family}}</td>
          <td class="th">{{PlanningBoardData.toProduceForecast}}</td>  
          <td class="th">{{PlanningBoardData.toProduce}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="placeholder" dragHandle=".ui-panel-titlebar">         
          <td class="th"></td>
          <td class="th"></td>
          <td class="th"></td>
          <td class="th"></td>
          <td class="th"></td>
          <td class="th"></td>
          <td class="th"></td>
          <td class="th"></td>            
      </tr>
  </tbody>
```

PlanningBoardData.Component.ts:-

```
export class PlanningBoardComponent implements OnInit {
         PlanningBoardDatas: PlanningBoardData[]=[];
    ....



        ngOnInit()
          {
            this.dateForm = this.fb.group({
              range: null
            });

            let targertElement = Object.assign({}, this.FineTunedDatas);    
            this.PlanningBoardDatas.push(targertElement);

            localStorage.clear();
            this.colors= ['#7FDBFF', '#39CCCC', '#3D9970', '#2ECC40 ', '#01FF70 ', 
            '#FFDC00'];
          }
}
```

FinedTunedData Interface is :-

```
  export interface FineTunedData {
  id: number;
  Article_ID: number;
  Description:string
  OpenOrderFinish:number
  Stockfinish:number
  NettoStockfinish:number
  OpenOrderPriceRAW:number
  NavisionCode:string
  Family:string
  PieceRAW:number
  OrdersRAW:number
  StockRAW:number
  ToProduce:number
  ForecastSalesWeeks:number
  ToProduceForecast:number

}
```

PlanningBoardData Interface is:-

```
export interface PlanningBoardData {
  id: number;
  Article_ID: number;
  Description:string
  OpenOrderFinish:number
  Stockfinish:number
  NettoStockfinish:number
  OpenOrderPriceRAW:number
  Family:string
  PieceRAW:number
  OrdersRAW:number
  StockRAW:number
  ToProduce:number
  ForecastSalesWeeks:number
  ToProduceForecast:number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to maintain two different lists instead of just one `FineTunedData`. There needs to be one list for the source table and another for the target table.

I see that you have applied many a pipes for the list in your source table. It is a bad practice to apply (so many) filters in template. It prohibits testability and also html template should not be the place where you keep your logic. Consider applying all your pipes in your `.ts` file. After applying the pipes you need to keep the result in a separate variable. Lets say `sourceList`.

And as mentioned earlier, you should have a separate list for target elements. Say `targetList`. To solve the problem of target elements keeping a reference to the source element, you might want to create a copy of the source element before adding the new element to the target list.

```
let targetElement = Object.assign({}, sourceElement);
let targetList.push(targetElement); // you might want to add the element to a specific index.
```

Comment: Hi Bharat, i tried with tow different list still i am facing same issue

Comment: Did you create a new copy of the object using:
let targetElement = Object.assign({}, sourceElement);

Comment: I am defining second list as ,  PlanningBoardDatas: PlanningBoardData[]=[]; then in Init() method i have let targertElement = Object.assign({}, this.FineTunedDatas);
    this.PlanningBoardDatas.push(targertElement);

Comment: This PlanningBoardData and FineTunedData is having same properties , but in above code while pushing targetElement data its giving error that propery missing

Comment: Hey Roshan, I think you want to move one element at a time from `FineTunedDatas` to the `PlanningBoardDatas` list. Is that correct?

Comment: I observe one more thing is when drag row from source table drag event from source component and target component both are getting executed..is this might be issue.

Comment: Can you update your question with the latest code that you have?

Comment: I am facing exactly same issue as this guy is facing , but his solution is not working for me line :https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/736

Comment: @Roshan04 please update the question with your latest code, else I will not be able to help you.

Comment: You need to use the current element being dragged not the whole `FineTunedDates`. It should be `let targertElement = Object.assign({}, this.elementBeingDragged);`. Also, this needs to be there in the onDrop event.

Comment: I tried above code in onDrop , still same issue is there